# Logging SSL ciphersuite used in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: security, iis, cryptography

Is there a way to see /log which cipher suites are (actively) being used to establish SSL connections on Windows Server 2008 R2?
Ideally on a per request basis, like an extra column in the IIS logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIS logs won't help you here, since the SSL connection is negotiated before any HTTP/application layer traffic starts flowing.

But what you can do is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh trace start capture=yes

Trace configuration:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Status:             Running
Trace File:         C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\NetTraces\NetTrace.etl
Append:             Off
Circular:           On
Max Size:           250 MB
Report:             Off


C:\Windows\system32>netsh trace stop
Correlating traces ... done
Generating data collection ... done
The trace file and additional troubleshooting information have been compiled as "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\NetTraces\NetTrace.cab".
File location = C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\NetTraces\NetTrace.etl
Tracing session was successfully stopped.
```

You can open that ETL file with Windows Performance Analyzer, and also with NetMon. (The latter will likely be more useful to you.)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2009/09/10/capturing-network-traffic-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx

Here's a screenshot of that trace file I just generated:

*(Open in new tab to see fullsize)*

[image: Netmon Trace]

**Edit:** To find the exact cipher mode being used, locate the "HandShake: Server Hello" packets:

[image: Netmon 2]

[Here is a Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299520) telling you how to interpret the bytes of the packet manually, but Netmon will do it for you.

You could come up with a packet trace filter that only contained packets of this nature. If there's a better way to get this data I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Close. I origally accepted the answer, but I can't work out from this what actual cipher suite is being used.  "TLS 1.0" is too vague.  I can see in the handshake packet a bunch of suites being offered ("TLSCipherSuites: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA   { 0x00, 0x88 } etc", but I can't tell which one is being picked.

Comment: For extra credit - I'd prefer something that grabbed less data than ETL - all I need is a historical log of ciphersuites used.

Comment: Edited my post. Yes the precise cipher mode is in there too.

Comment: What about constant monitoring to collect statistics about what protocol/suites are being used on server? Is trace appropriate to be running on webserver 24/7 performance wise? Ofcourse netsh can be limited to capture subset of traffic (like port, not sure if only TLS handshake can be filtered out), but what would be community opinion?